# Is it possible to select all friends by one click to invite/add them to an event?

Tags: facebook, events, list

At the moment there is only one more or less quick possibility to add friends - using combination of TAB+Space, but if you have more than 200 attendants, it makes quite annoying to press 200 times 2 buttons.

Comment: Hi, Aleksandr. This forum is for programmers to discuss programming questions and problems. Sorry. This question belongs in another forum.

Answer (score 2):

Although this probably doesn't belong on this forum, try this in the address bar:

```
javascript:elms=document.getElementById('friends').getElementsByTagName('li');for(var fid in elms){if(typeof elms[fid] === 'object'){fs.click(elms[fid]);}}
```

And just fyi, just a simple google search for these sort of things will yield a myriad of answers.